# Swift correct break multi-layer switch

Tags: swift

I'm rewriting a code from java to swift and need to break a multi-layered switches right way. In Java it looks like :

```
 block0 : switch (topSwithch) {
    case one: {
        switch (innerSwitch) {
        case insideCase: {
             if (something){
                break block0;
            }
// etc
```

So, I'm breaking one switch from another. How do I do it in swift ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what it'd look like in Swift. I did this in a playground with hardcoded values for the variables:

```
let topSwitch = 1
let innerSwitch = 4
let one = 1
let insideCase = 4
let something = true

block0 : switch (topSwitch) { //first switch labeled "block0", switching on topSwitch
    case one: //topSwitch is 1, one is 1
        switch (innerSwitch) { // switching on innerSwitch
            case insideCase: // both are 1
                if (something){ // if true
                    break block0; // break from "block0"
                }
            default: break // else
        }
    default: break // else
}
```

Comment: @user2976267, yeah pretty crazy!